# how to add pref counters to System Under Test Resources (vs2012 load test)

Tags: c#, web-services, testing, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I run a load test (vs2012).

How can I add pref counters to the machine under test?

In the load test summery I see a table with header:

`System Under Test Resources`

but I see no data in the table itself

How can I set counter to the remote machine (over LAN) under test?

I tried to add `qa-srv17` as:

[image]

Comment: What type of performance counters do you want to add?

Comment: In the System Under Test there is a `Test Agent` installed. So, through the Load Test editor, you can [add new Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404704.aspx) in the `Test Agent Counter Set` or [add a new Custom Counter Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404668.aspx).

Comment: @Schaliasos how can i verify `Test Agent` is isntalled there? The machine under test doesn't appear in the `manage counter sets`.I tried to add it manually ("add computer" and added `\\qa-srv17`) but it did nothing.

Comment: If the machine is in the same domain (I think it is) then just add the computer name (`qa-srv17`) in the `Manage Counter Sets`. To verify that you have access to the perf counters of the machine under test, open the `Server Explorer` of visual studio and connect to the machine (qa-srv17). Then expand the tree and check that you can see the performance counters.

Comment: I managed to add it in the `server explorer`, but I yet again - how can I drug and drop `qa-srv17` to be monitored? as when I add it with the loadtest wizard - I see no data. I don't see `qa-srv17` in the `counters panel` let alon in any summary.

Comment: Are you selecting at least one `Counter Set` from the load test wizard for the `qa-srv17`? Check this [image](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/UserFiles/ArticlesFiles/Ambily.raj_634152917655181328_9.jpg) (although it is from vs-2010 I think it's the same).

Comment: Yes. see my photo in the updated question.

Comment: Try without the "\\", just `qa-srv17`.